# install leiningen windows cygwin

Tags: clojure, cygwin, leiningen

I'm trying install leiningen on windows and cygwin.
When executed the last shell script seems works fine.

Below the execution log:

```
$ ./lein.sh
which: no lein.sh in (/usr/local/opt/java8/bin:../../opt/gradle/3.2.1/bin:.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.7.1-standalone.jar:/usr/local/bin:/opt/devtools/scripts:C:/devtools/opt/ibm/wlp/8.5.5.9/bin:/opt/nodejs:/usr/local/opt/tomcat/bin:/usr/local/opt/was7/bin:/usr/local/opt/scala/bin:/usr/local/opt/groovy/bin:/usr/local/opt/ant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/conemu/ConEmu/Scripts:/opt/conemu:/opt/conemu/ConEmu:/c/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/AXALTO/Access Client/v5:/c/Program Files (x86)/AXALTO/Access Client/v5:/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Check Point/UIFramework 3.0/Bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/CheckPoint/Endpoint Security/Endpoint Common/bin$)
Downloading Leiningen to C:\devtools\home\790530\.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.7.1-standalone.jar now...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   605    0   605    0     0    685      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   689
100 14.6M  100 14.6M    0     0   372k      0  0:00:40  0:00:40 --:--:--  402k
Leiningen is a tool for working with Clojure projects.

Several tasks are available:
change              Rewrite project.clj by applying a function.
check               Check syntax and warn on reflection.
classpath           Print the classpath of the current project.
clean               Remove all files from project's target-path.
compile             Compile Clojure source into .class files.
deploy              Build and deploy jar to remote repository.
deps                Download all dependencies.
do                  Higher-order task to perform other tasks in succession.
help                Display a list of tasks or help for a given task.
install             Install the current project to the local repository.
jar                 Package up all the project's files into a jar file.
javac               Compile Java source files.
new                 Generate project scaffolding based on a template.
plugin              DEPRECATED. Please use the :user profile instead.
pom                 Write a pom.xml file to disk for Maven interoperability.
release             Perform :release-tasks.
repl                Start a repl session either with the current project or standalone.
retest              Run only the test namespaces which failed last time around.
run                 Run a -main function with optional command-line arguments.
search              Search remote maven repositories for matching jars.
show-profiles       List all available profiles or display one if given an argument.
test                Run the project's tests.
trampoline          Run a task without nesting the project's JVM inside Leiningen's.
uberjar             Package up the project files and dependencies into a jar file.
update-in           Perform arbitrary transformations on your project map.
upgrade             Upgrade Leiningen to specified version or latest stable.
vcs                 Interact with the version control system.
version             Print version for Leiningen and the current JVM.
with-profile        Apply the given task with the profile(s) specified.

Run `lein help $TASK` for details.

Global Options:
  -o             Run a task offline.
  -U             Run a task after forcing update of snapshots.
  -h, --help     Print this help or help for a specific task.
  -v, --version  Print Leiningen's version.

These aliases are available:
downgrade, expands to upgrade

See also: readme, faq, tutorial, news, sample, profiles, deploying, gpg,
mixed-source, templates, and copying.
```

**But only downloaded a jar file**

Is it right?

if executed java -jar leiningen-2.7.1-standalone.jar

```
Clojure 1.8.0

user=>
```

**So only like that i'm able to execute clojure but i can't execute lein commands.
Someone could help me please?**

Comment: Try the four-step installation instructions at [leiningen.org](http://leiningen.org/): download the `lein` script, put it on your `PATH`, make it executable, then run it simply with `lein`. No need for `lein.sh` or `java -jar`.

Comment: https://leiningen.org/#install

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you successfully installed lein.

then try running

```
lein repl
```

and if that works

```
lein new hello-world
```